# Using multiples of 5 as a variable to use modulo more easily

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm relatively new to Python, and coding in general (first-semester, intro computer science, I'm not a comp sci major.), and a homework assignment has me trying to figure out how many numbers *between* two numbers contain "5" (Such as between 105 and 168 there are 16 numbers that contain 5.) I started my code with:

```
def give_me_five(start, end):
    ctr = start
    max = end
    numberoffives = 0
    while ctr <= end:
        print (ctr)
        if ctr % 5 == 0 and (ctr % 10 != 0):
            elif ctr % 5 == 0 and (ctr % 10 == (somethingsomethingmultiplesof5)
        numberoffives += 1
    if ctr // 10 == 5:
        numberoffives += 1
    ctr += 1

return numberoffives
```

The problem I'm encountering is that I can't use this to check for numbers in the 50s, 150s, etc... I tried using the ctr % 5 == 0 and (ctr % 10 == ) bit there to try and include them but now I can't figure out a way to proceed at all, and frankly I feel like I'm overcomplicating things. Does anyone have any advice for how to make my code actually work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the digit `5` can be anywhere in a number it's easiest to convert each integer between the two numbers to a string instead so that you can use the `in` operator to check if `5` is a substring:

```
def give_me_five(start, end):
    return sum('5' in str(i) for i in range(start, end + 1))
```

or if you prefer to do it with math, you can keep dividing a given number by 10 while checking if the remainder is 5 until the quotient becomes 0:

```
def give_me_five(start, end):
    count = 0
    for i in range(start, end + 1):
        while i > 0:
            if i % 10 == 5:
                count += 1
                break
            i //= 10
    return count
```

so that:

```
give_me_five(105, 168)
```

returns: `16`

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding correctly, we want to do: for each number `x` in range, check to see if any of its digits `digit` is equal to 5.

How do we do this?

One thing we could do is cast the digit => string, and then check to see if the substring '5' exists. But this is a naive solution, requiring more memory and time to store all the digits into a string (rather than the few bytes necessary to represent the existing int).

So a smarter way would be to continually extract the least significant digit (`digit = x % 10`), check `if digit == 5`, and then divide out the least significant digit to repeat (`x //= 10 WHILE x > 0`).

Comment: I think you may be incorrect in your statement about the performance differences between the two approaches. The string checking method is faster on my computer and on [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY3dCgIhEIXve4phIVZhaZUwIrB3cVktIX/QEezpzWXvgi6am8PA@c4X3/gM/tyadTEkBLROWzzEZD2S/TntQcZcHDGkUhMSVLAekvIPTTgTE/DLldJxyhpLlKORL@WWVUG91TsD5Vcg9ciZlAI63EfmmbMN8MUtOknO@lH6t/endhDD1syYOvitae0D "Try It Online")

Comment: I suppose that could be true for small integers. But certainly it will take more memory to represent a char array than an int.

Comment: More memory, maybe. But with time as the measurement, string comparison seems to win out every time. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tY5BCsIwFET3nuJTkKZQ7S@lC5V4l5QmGvCnIf2BePqYUjcewNkMs5g349/8XNyQsyW/BAa2pC0ffLCOxR7Ou4l6jSSMSI1ZAiSwDoJyDy3oNCBiC9Q0dbtqjl7WJC9f3Yx8KZpmBema7gjKzSDSsUcpRyigAuy6HreuizTpIHss6U8PqrHaaiuHQvldzPkD "Try It Online")